# same origin policy error when creating map

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

I tried running the code below that creates a map using OpenLayers. The code is an example from the [GeoServer Beginner's Guide](https://www.packtpub.com/hardware-and-creative/geoserver-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide).

The code creates a map and adds a couple of layers to it. The client-side code (below) is loaded from the local filesystem and the layer data is downloaded from Geoserver running locally on post 8080.

The code is supposed to create a map and add a couple of layers to it. The second layer is added by the `addGeoRSS` function. The first layer is added successfully, but adding the second layer fails with the following error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=tiger:poi&styles=&bbox=-74.0118315772888,40.70754683896324,-74.00153046439813,40.719885123828675&width=427&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application%2Frss%2Bxml. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Given that both layers are downloaded from the same host, I would expect both of them to fail, why does only the second one cause problems?

```
var GEOSERVERBASE = "http://localhost:8080";
var CountyLayer = 'tiger:tl_2011_us_county';
var map;

function mapinitialize() {

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        maxResolution:'auto',
        projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    });
    layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        CountyLayer, GEOSERVERBASE + "/geoserver/tiger/wms",
        {
            layers: CountyLayer,
            format: 'image/png'
        }
    );

    // first (successful) request to Geoserver running at http://localhost:8080
    map.addLayer(layer);
    map.zoomTo(9);
    map.panTo(new OpenLayers.LonLat(-73.99, 40.75)); 

    // second request to Geoserver that causes a CORS error
    addGeoRSS();
}

function addGeoRSS() {

    var value = GEOSERVERBASE + '/geoserver/tiger/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=tiger:poi&styles=&bbox=-74.0118315772888,40.70754683896324,-74.00153046439813,40.719885123828675&width=427&height=512&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application%2Frss%2Bxml';
    var georss = new OpenLayers.Layer.GeoRSS('Tiger POI', value);
    map.addLayer(georss);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first layer request is for an image (`.png`) and images are not subject to CORS restrictions. The reason for the CORS error, however, remains the fact that you're loading client code with `file://` and then trying to load a (non-image) resource with `http://`

Comment: This doesn't explain why I only get a CORS error for the second layer, given that both layers are retrieved from http://localhost:8080

Comment: It's not possible to get a CORS error from an initial request. **Cross Origin** means that a resource loaded from one origin (`file://`) is trying to access a resource in a different origin (`http://`). If that doesn't make sense, research CORS a bit, e.g at Wikipedia or via Google.

Comment: I think you're missing my point. The JS code above makes 2 requests to http://localhost:8080, the first one succeeds, the second causes a CORS error. I've added some comments to the code, to make this clearer